# How to remove microseconds from timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have microseconds that I want to essentially truncate from a  pandas column. I tried something like `analyze_me['how_long_it_took_to_order'] = analyze_me['how_long_it_took_to_order'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond=0)` but to this error came up `replace() takes no keyword arguments`.

For example: I want 00:19:58.582052  to become 00:19:58 or 00:19:58.58

[image]

Comment: You should consider changing your data to timedelta or a timestamp (if you have the date along with it) from string. There isn't a good reason to keep it as string. Then you can use the excellent `dt` accessor with the `floor` method to truncate. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `how_long_it_took_to_order` column seems to be of string (`object`) dtype.

So try this:

```
analyze_me['how_long_it_took_to_order'] = \
    analyze_me['how_long_it_took_to_order'].str.split('.').str[0]
```

or:

```
analyze_me['how_long_it_took_to_order'] = \
    analyze_me['how_long_it_took_to_order'].str.replace('(\.\d{2})\d+', r'\1')
```

for "centiseconds", like: `00:19:58.58`

Comment: That looks like it would remove the fractional part entirely.

Comment: @pvg, yes, that's how i understood: `I want 00:19:58.582052 to become 00:19:58 or 00:19:58.58`

Comment: It's a little vague but the title says 'microseconds'. The second version of the string is one without microseconds (goes up to 100ths).

Comment: wow, awesome! That worked great. it became `00:19:58`. If I want to keep the 100ths on there for 00:19:58.58 what would I need to change in the code? What does the \ accomplish here, or is that just from the console itself? Thanks again guys-really appreciate it @MaxU and @pvg

Comment: The \ is just line continuation, telling python to treat both lines as if it was one lone line. The 100ths code is still a little iffy since it would fail in cases where the precision is not exactly 6 decimal digits.

Comment: Yeah, thought so. Still learning here :P I think what I was asking was  how to choose the  number in the last [] such as str[0] or str[:-4]. I'll try out that centiseconds option

Comment: If the column had a date like `2014-10-26 13:51:59.898924` would it make a difference when dropping the microseconds, or would it know to just cut off microseconds?

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to convert your string in to a timedelta with `pd.to_timedelta` and then take advantage of the excellent dt accessor with the floor method which truncates based on string. Here are the first two rows of your data.

```
df['how_long_it_took_to_order'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['how_long_it_took_to_order'])
df['how_long_it_took_to_order'].dt.floor('s')

0   00:19:58
1   00:25:09
```

Can round to the hundredth of a second.

```
df['how_long_it_took_to_order'].dt.floor('10ms')

0   00:19:58.580000
1   00:25:09.100000
```

Here I create some a Series of timedeltas and then use the `dt` accessor with the `floor` method to truncate down to the nearest microsecond.

```
d = pd.timedelta_range(0, periods=6, freq='644257us')
s = pd.Series(d)
s

0          00:00:00
1   00:00:00.644257
2   00:00:01.288514
3   00:00:01.932771
4   00:00:02.577028
5   00:00:03.221285
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Now truncate

```
s.dt.floor('s')

0   00:00:00
1   00:00:00
2   00:00:01
3   00:00:01
4   00:00:02
5   00:00:03
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you want to truncate to the nearest hundredth of a second do this:

```
s.dt.floor('10ms')

0          00:00:00
1   00:00:00.640000
2   00:00:01.280000
3   00:00:01.930000
4   00:00:02.570000
5   00:00:03.220000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Its fine if he has strings. Just conver it to timedelta. String length will be variable but a timedelta is exact

Comment: This seems like a much saner answer as opposed to munging strings.

Comment: I think this solution will not work properly as OP has both strings representing only time and date+time - something like this: `pd.to_timedelta(['00:19:58.582052', '2014-10-26 13:51:59.898924'])` - which won't work...

Comment: @MaxU that's mentioned in a comment to your answer, conditionally. It's not really clear what the poster actually has but converting to some time representation still seems like a sensible way to go.

Comment: @pvg, can you propose a solution which would solve OPs problem and wouldn't be "munging strings"? ;-)

Comment: @MaxU It's not really clear exactly what data the OP has. It seems pretty self-evident (to me, at least) that if you want to process or format time, it's much easier if you use a sensible representation of time.

Comment: This answer is more correct since id does not convert Timedelta to string and back.

Answer (score 3):

I needed this for a simple script where I wasn't using Pandas, and came up with a simple hack which should work everywhere.

```py
age = age - timedelta(microseconds=age.microseconds)
```

where `age` is my `timedelta` object.

You can't directly modify the `microseconds` member of a `timedelta` object because it's immutable, but of course, you can replace it with another immutable object.