# How to show timedelta without miliseconds

Tags: python, timedelta

I have as a result of dividing timedelta like 0 days 00:16:24.333333333 in dataframe in colums result['avgTime']. How can I change format to 0 days 00:16:24 I can't use strftime

Comment: @ThierryLathuille That question is about `datetime` not `timedelta`. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46204241) would be a more appropriate duplicate target.